# Was the predator that fights Dutch a renegade?

Tags: predator, predator-series

I was recalling the events, and there were some points that lead me to think that.

- The Yautja seem to hunt in groups, at least most of the time. This predator was acting alone.
- The Yautja recovers the bodies of the deceased after losing a battle. The guy was left to be kicked by Dutch and nobody appeared.
- When the Yautja lose there is always some proof of the achievement given to the winner. Dutch does not receive anything (perhaps some radiation dose by the detonation of a small H bomb).
- There seems to be a spacecraft near the group of hunters in operation. At the start this guy was expelled from a spacecraft.
- The Yautja always try to fight, be it win or lose, so wouldn't it be dishonoring to itself to self destruct?

If this predator was alone, then in the event of defeat, who is supposed to give the winner the token of "appreciation", if there is no other Yautja.

So is this one a renegade, rebel or convict punished to be killed/dishonored at some point in the Earth?

Comment: FWIW Predator (2018)'s movie poster is that of a Predator having seemingly killed another Predator. This answer mentions an outcast group of Predators: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174043/what-are-the-rules-of-engagement-observed-by-the-predator-aliens-in-the-predator